# Cartesian equation of uniformly accelerated motion

Tags: geometry, quadratics, conic-sections, parametric, kinematics

### Problem

Let $\xi,\eta$ be the horizontal and vertical coordinates of a plane. Consider the following sequence of point
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\xi_k &= \xi_0 + kT \dot{\xi}_0 + k^2 \frac{T^2}{2} u_\xi\\
\eta_k &= \eta_0 + kT \dot{\eta}_0 + k^2 \frac{T^2}{2} u_\eta\\
\end{aligned} \qquad k=0,1,2\dots,K\tag{1}\end{equation}
where:

- $\xi_0$, $\eta_0$ is a given starting position;
- $\dot{\xi}_0$, $\dot{\eta}_0$ is a given starting velocity;
- $u_{\xi}$, $u_{\eta}$ is a given acceleration, which is constant respect the index $k$;
- $T>0$ is a given sampling time;
- $K>0$ is the index of the last point, and is given.

I'm quite sure that, excluding some special case where the trajectory is a line, in general every point $\{\xi_k,\eta_k\}_{k=0}^K$ lies on a suitable parabola, so the problem is the following:

**problem** if it exists, find the Cartesian equation of the underling parabola.

---

### My attempt

First of all a quick change of coordinates that simplify the notation
\begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
\Delta \xi_k &\triangleq \xi_k-\xi_0\\ 
\Delta \eta_k &\triangleq \eta_k-\eta_0\\ 
\end{aligned}\end{equation*}
so $(1)$ simplifies in
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\Delta\xi_k &= kT \dot{\xi}_0 + k^2 \frac{T^2}{2} u_\xi\\
\Delta \eta_k &= kT \dot{\eta}_0 + k^2 \frac{T^2}{2} u_\eta\\
\end{aligned} \qquad k=0,1,2\dots,K\tag{1}\end{equation}
now the idea is to solve the first equation with respect $T$, then plug the result in the second equation and hoping to find an expression of the form
\begin{equation}\Delta \eta_k=a(\Delta \xi_k)^2+b\Delta \xi_k+c \qquad k=0,1,\dots,K\end{equation}
or in the form
\begin{equation}\Delta \xi_k=a(\Delta \eta_k)^2+b\Delta \eta_k+c \qquad k=0,1,\dots,K\end{equation}
for suitables $a,b,c$ depending on the data $\dot{\xi}_0, \dot{\eta}_0, u_{\xi}, u_{\eta}, T$.

---

#### step 1: solving respect $T$

If I'm not wrong, $T$ is given by the two solutions
\begin{equation*}T=\frac{-k\dot{\xi}_0\pm\sqrt{(k\dot{\xi}_0)^2-4\frac{k^2 u_{\xi}}{2}(-\Delta\xi_k)}}{2\frac{k^2 u_{\xi}}{2}}=\frac{-\dot{\xi}_0 \pm \sqrt{\dot{\xi}_0^2+2u_{\xi}\Delta \xi_k}}{k u_\xi}\end{equation*}

#### step 2: plugging $T$ into the second equation

Now I have
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\Delta \eta_k &= k\dot{\eta}_0\left(\frac{-\dot{\xi}_0 \pm \sqrt{\dot{\xi}_0^2+2u_{\xi}\Delta \xi_k}}{k u_\xi}\right) 
+\frac{k^2 u_{\eta}}{2}\left(\frac{-\dot{\xi}_0 \pm \sqrt{\dot{\xi}_0^2+2u_{\xi}\Delta \xi_k}}{k u_\xi}\right)^2\\
&=\frac{\dot{\eta}_0}{u_\xi}\left(-\dot{\xi}_0 \pm \sqrt{\dot{\xi}_0^2+2u_{\xi}\Delta \xi_k}\right)+\frac{u_\eta}{2 u_{\xi}^2}\left(-\dot{\xi}_0 \pm \sqrt{\dot{\xi}_0^2+2u_{\xi}\Delta \xi_k}\right)^2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and this is my stopping point since I'dont know how to rearrange the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now the idea is to solve the first equation with respect $T$, then plug the result in the second equation and hoping to find an expression of the form
> \begin{equation}\Delta \eta_k=a(\Delta \xi_k)^2+b\Delta \xi_k+c \qquad k=0,1,\dots,K\end{equation}
> or in the form
> \begin{equation}\Delta \xi_k=a(\Delta \eta_k)^2+b\Delta \eta_k+c \qquad k=0,1,\dots,K\end{equation}
> for suitables $a,b,c$ depending on the data $\dot{\xi}_0, \dot{\eta}_0, u_{\xi}, u_{\eta}, T$.

This is an interesting idea. The limitation of this approach is that
$\Delta \eta_k=a(\Delta \xi_k)^2+b\Delta \xi_k+c$
describes a parabola whose axis is parallel to the vertical axis and
$\Delta \xi_k=a(\Delta \eta_k)^2+b\Delta \eta_k+c$
describes a parabola whose axis is parallel to the horizontal axis.
But in general the axis of a parabola can be parallel to an arbitrary line through the origin, not necessarily one of the chosen axes.

Rather than translate the system of coordinates, try *rotating* the system of coordinates:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} \xi' \\ \eta' \end{pmatrix} 
= \begin{pmatrix} p & -q \\ q & p \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} \xi \\ \eta \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $p^2 + q^2 = 1$,
in such a way that you get a formula
$$ \xi_k'=a(\eta_k')^2+b\eta_k'+c. $$

The first step in this direction is to find $p$ and $q$ such that
$$
\eta_k' = c_2 + b_2 (kT),
$$
that is, eliminate the one of the quadratic terms. Then you can solve for $kT$ as a degree-one polynomial in $\eta_k',$ and having done that, can plug that polynomial in $\eta_k'$ for every value of $kT$ in the formula for $\xi_k'$, which will then turn out to be a quadratic polynomial in $\eta_k'$.

Note that if you use an arbitrary rotation matrix
$\begin{pmatrix} p & -q \\ q & p \end{pmatrix},$
the formula you get for $\eta_k'$ is a quadratic polynomial in $kT$ whose quadratic term is
$$ \left(\frac12 p u_\xi + \frac12 q u_\eta\right) (kT)^2.$$
So it comes down to finding $p$ and $q$ such that
$p u_\xi + q u_\eta = 0$ and $p^2 + q^2 = 1,$
followed by a lot of algebra if you want to find the values of $a,$ $b,$ and $c$ in terms of the original given information.

Less algebra is required if you merely want to convince someone like me that
$\xi_k'$ is a quadratic polynomial in $\eta_k',$
that is, $\xi_k'=a(\eta_k')^2+b\eta_k'+c$ for constants $a,$ $b,$ and $c$
that could (in principle) be computed in terms of the given information if you really wanted to do so,
which says the points $(\xi_k,\eta_k)$ all like on a single parabola parallel to the $\xi'$ axis.

---

Incidentally, I find it easier to do the continuous version of this problem,
in which we let
\begin{align}
\xi &= \xi_0 + \dot{\xi}_0 t + \frac12 u_\xi t^2, \\
\eta &= \eta_0 + \dot{\eta}_0 t + \frac12 u_\eta t^2 
\end{align}
so that $t = kT,$ $\xi = \xi_k,$ and $\eta = \eta_k$
satisfy the system of equations for each $k = 0, 1, \ldots, K.$
Once we have shown a solution for all real values of $t,$
we know it is also valid for the $K+1$ particular values $t = kT.$

Comment: thanks a lot for the clear answer, tomorrow I will try to follow your suggestions and I will see if I can get the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much, the idea to rotate the axis works like a charm. I've not found an explicit equation of the Cartesian equation, but I've devised a very simple procedure to compute numerically the trajectory without using the sequence defined in $(1)$.
It turns out that the trajectory, when the starting velocity is not null and not aligned to the acceleration, is a parabola.